# Access PasswordValidator in Data Annotation Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How do I access the PasswordValidator properties from a viewmodel to decorate the input password validation?

For example, this is in IdentityConfig.cs/Create

```
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 7,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
```

Then in the AccountViewModels.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute `[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]`  prevents the form being submitted until the password input is correct length. If I remove it the form can get posted but will produce an error due to the `PassordValidator` so I think it's preferable to have the attribute so nothing can be posted until correct.

How do I access the PasswordValidator properties inside the RegisterViewModel?

Eg something like

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = passwordValidator.RequiredLength)]
```

Comment: Add a `[RegularExpression]` attribute that takes all the requirements into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way, but considering you want to share the configuration between the passwordvalidator and the viewmodel and keep them in sync, you could externalise the configuration using application settings which would allow you to keep the two classes decoupled.

So you could add an appsetting to your web.config (or appsettings.json if using .NET Core)

example (pseudoish code, not checked it compiles but shows the idea)

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="passwordminlength" value="6" />
...
</appSettings>
```

attribute:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = (int) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passwordminlength")]
```

validator:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
   RequiredLength = (int) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passwordminlength")
   ...
}
```